# Data bind visible is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to do set the Data bind visibility on the section like below

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: !sameAsShippingAddress() || !hasCustomerAccNum()">
```

Both the `sameAsShippingAddress` and `sameAsShippingAddress` are the check box fields, when either one of the checkbox is selected the the div class should be invisible

Two check box fields are

```
            <div class="form-check" style="float:left;">
                <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="HasCustomerAccNum" value="HasCustomerAccNum" data-bind="checked: hasCustomerAccNum" />
                <label>Has Customer Account Number?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check" style="float:right;">
                <input class="form-check-input position-static" type="checkbox" id="SameAsShippingAddress" value="SameAsShippingAddress" data-bind="checked: sameAsShippingAddress" />
                <label>Billing address is same as Shipping Address</label>
            </div>
```

and the js file, I set their fields as

```
self.sameAsShippingAddress = ko.observable(false);
self.hasCustomerAccNum = ko.observable(false);
```

The issue is only when both the fields are checked the div class is invisible

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here. I want the right side section to be invisible even when one check box is checked

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6" data-bind="visible: !sameAsShippingAddress() && !hasCustomerAccNum()">
```